# How to display data from Observable in Angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, api, get, observable

I have a problem with displaying Observable object in component.

My Json structure is:

```
{ 
  "data": [
    {
     "id": "123",
     "name": "test",
    } 
  ], 
  "pagination": null
}
```

So I have created interface to map this json to .ts

```
export interface Paginated<T>{
   data: Array<T>;
   pagination: Pagination;
}
```

In my component I have Observable object for this json:

```
 this.httpClient.get<Paginated<Event>>(`${environment.apiUrl}/events`);
```

And I do not have idea how to display property **data** which is inside Observable<Paginated> with using async pipe, because this json is not an array - it is object with two property - **data** and **pagination** so I cannot just simply use *ngFor with async pipe, because this object is not an array.

So my question is how to display in component this property data when I received Observable<Paginated> I cannot use *ngFor... how to unpack data property from this Observable<Paginated>

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
response$: Observable<Paginated<Event>>;
constructor() {
  response$ = this.httpClient.get<Paginated<Event>>(`${environment.apiUrl}/events`);
}
```

and in your component

```
<li *ngFor="let dataEl of (response$ | async)?.data">{{dataEl.name}}</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case when you want to extract the value out of an observable, you can subscribe to its value in the following way:

```
data: Array<T> = [];

constructor(){
   this.httpClient.get<Paginated<Event>>(`${environment.apiUrl}/events`).subscribe((response) => {

      // then extract the data from response over here
      const {data, pagination} = response;

      // assign the extracted 'data' array to a component variable named data.
      this.data = data;

   });
}
```

And in the html template you can then use

```
<li *ngFor="let el of (data)">{{data.name}}</li>
```